# How to find departments which has no employees without using nested query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
employee(e_id,e_name,d_id),department(d_id,d_name)
```

my query is:

```
select d.d_name from department d where d.d_id not in (
select distinct e.d_id from employee e);
```

is there any alternative way to do this?.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   select department.* from department
     left join employee
       on  employee.d_id = department.d_id
     where employee.d_id is null
```